# Zero opacity on page load, but using progressive enhancement approach?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to have some images fade in on a web page as the page loads, so starting with opacity:0 then fade to opacity:1 using an image-loading script.

However, for the script to work, the images have to initially be invisible. So if I set the opacity to zero using CSS, if a user does not have javaScript, they will not see any of the images.

To combat this, I have tried applying the zero opacity via jQuery like this...

```
 $(".images").css('opacity', 0);
```

...however I still get a flicker of the images at 100% opacity, and then the jQuery kicks in, hiding them, only for them to fade in again with the image-loading script.

So what is the safest way to hide the images initially before they are loaded, so that even if the user has javaScript disabled, they will still be able to see the images, they just wont get the fancy image loading effect?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you hide the image on load then have jquery make it visible before doing the fade?

Comment: Does a large part of your audience disable javascript? I believe it's quite rare..

Comment: I agree Rich however the part I wish to display is quite a crucial part of the site, and I've spent a lot of time in making the site as accessible to everyone as possible, so would be a shame to ruin that for this small issue

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean CSgoose. Hide with jQuery? The CSS will still flash it on occasions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this is my last attempt because you're all over the place:

```
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
.images {
opacity:1;
}
</style>
</noscript>
```

in a style sheet:

```
.images {
opacity: 0;
}
```

in jquery :

```
$('.images').fadeIn();
```

If someone doesn't have javascript then it will hit the noscript tag and change the opacity of the images back to 1. Honestly though who doesn't have javascript these days?

Comment: You have completely misunderstood the question. I am trying to find a safer way of hiding the images initially, ideally using javascript

Comment: This is even worse! So if the user does not have javaScript, the whole page will be blank? I am looking for a fallback where if the user does not have javaScript, then at least the page and images will still be visible, they just wont get the cool image loading effect

Comment: You're saying conflicting things! you just said this " I am trying to find a safer way of hiding the images initially, ideally using javascript" why did you say "ideally using javascript" then!??? Make up your mind please... if you want to do this without javascript than i'm sorry but there probably isn't a good way to do this. You want to do this ideally WITHOUT using javascript...

Comment: BTW hiding the images initially using CSS which was my solution has very little risk to it so I'm not sure what your issue with this is... CSS will never not work in a browser. So either i'm not understanding your question because it's asked incorrectly or you're not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: ok so I want to hide the images using javascript, which prevents the early flash of images displaying.

Comment: see my updated answer you can hide them css then set them to fade in with jquery and then if they don't have javascript enabled it will hit the no script tag and just make them visible this way they will be visible from the start, fade in, and if someone has no js they don't get any fancy pants fading they just get the images.

Comment: ok you do not seem to understand how progressive enhancement works. The risk is not with CSS. If i hide images with css, then the user does not support js, the CSS will be hidden by default, and no js means the image-loading script will not work. So no images for the user. Of course CSS will work in browsers, I am talking about the possibility of javaScript not working.

Comment: Are you reading my answer dude go up and look a noscript tag will get fired if the person does not have javascript and it will then show the images. I understand perfectly well what progressive enhancement is.

Comment: ah yes just saw this, this is the good solution I was looking for, thanks

Comment: `<script type="text/css">` is that reliably parsed? Maybe a typo?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an "image-loading-script" aka loading it via js, you can do something like this:

```
var img = $(document.createElement('img'));
img.on('load.fade-image', function () {
  // Note: set opacity of the image before adding it to the DOM, this way it will be rendered with 0 opecity
  img.css('opacity', 0);
  img.appendTo('body');
});
img.attr('src', 'http://some-url');
```